# Topological Invarient Z2

Tags: topological-insulators

For a condensed matter person, it is easy to understand the term called 'topological invariant z2' for a topological insulator. However, is there anyway so that material scientist can easily understand the physical meaning of this term. I am aware that enough information is available explaining topological properties using geometrical objects that are preserved during continuous transformation. However, what is preserved (considering in term of z2) for a TI (3D or 2D). Is this extend for Weyl semimetals also?

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 4) If you get a satisfactory answer, remember to accept it by clicking on the green checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

One clear experimental signature of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ invariant for the 3D TI is the topological magnetoelectric effect. See this nice paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.3537 for more details.